# Нескрываемая кнопка на экране

Tags: java, android

Как сделать нескрываемую кнопку на экране в ОС Андроид. Нужно чтоб при выходе на главный экран, заходе в другие приложения она оставалась и ее можно было таскать по экрану. Идей нет( Это вообще активити?

Comment: нет это параметр Layoult, посмотрите зачем нужно разрешение https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW ну и учтите что такие кнопки могут как Fictus быть распознаны.

Comment: @pavel спасибо.

Comment: Если я Вас правильно понял, то может вот это поможет http://stackoverflow.com/a/4482868